# A question about non-linearity of an in-amp gain

Tags: gain, instrumentation-amplifier, non-linear

I'm observing nonlinearities in microvolt range inputs on an instrumentation amplifier. Here is the [amplififer datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8221.pdf) and its gain is supposed to be:

G = 1 + (49.4 kΩ/Rg)

And the inputs to this amplifier(from a strain-gage) will be in -/+2mV range in my case.

So I wanted to see the gain at different differential inputs in simulation.

Below the inputs to the amplifier are +/-1mV, so the differential input signal Vsig = (+Sig) -(-Sig) = 2mV and Vout = 1.6V. Here the gain is then around 780. Below is the plot for these:

[image]

And this time below the inputs to the amplifier are +/-1μV, so the Vsig = 0.2μV and Vout = -38mV. But this time the gain is around 190k(LTspice shows 19k). Below is the plot for this case:

[image]

To see this non-linearity I made a DC sweep for 0.1mV...2mV range and here is what I get:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? If not would this nonlinearity have bad results for my -/+2mV range strain-gage inputs to the amplifier.

**Edit:**

Common mode voltage added to the inputs as will exist in real scenario:

[image]

Comment: AD8221 has up to 25 uV offset voltage. That alone will produce a  nonlinear response, probably noticeable for input amplitudes below 100 uV.

Comment: @ThePhoton Does that mean for small strain changes there will be great error in measurements? What could be the workaround for these in electrical side besides using more sensitive gages?

Comment: What are your power supplies, and are you good with the allowed common mode input ranges?

Comment: You can calibrate the offset and subtract it off before outputting a reading.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh you mean making an offset measurement before any stress applied and subtract that voltage from the voltage when there is stress?

Comment: @Scott Seidman Power supplies will be +-5V dual power supply or I will use voltage converter IC to obtain -5V from 5V supply. Common mode voltage will be 2.5V because I will use 5V excitation for a full strain-gage. I checked the diamond the common mode is in the range of allowed. Please see this link, I used the tool from Analog Devices here my setup: http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/diamond/#difL=-0.002&difR=0.002&difSl=-0.002&gain=800&l=2.1&pr=AD8221&r=2.9&sl=2.9&tab=1&ty=1&vn=-5&vp=5&vr=0

Comment: Probably you'd have to do something like that anyway because the 0-strain resistance of your strain gauge won't be perfectly matched to the other resistors in your bridge circuit anyway. (Or if you have a potentiometer in one arm of the bridge, when you adjust it to zero the bridge, you'll fix the in-amp offset also).

Comment: Looks like you're good, so long as your output is between -1V and 3V -- and your nonlinearity may be an offset issue.  What happens for 0V in?  Also, what you describe in the comment is not what you've simulated.

Comment: @Scott Seidman I get around 34μV at the output when inputs are shorted(zero voltage difference at the input). What was not matching in comment and simulation? I didn't notice actually.

Comment: The 2.5V common mode range is not in your sim.

Comment: Actually, I misread the diamond before.  You have a much wider output voltage range than what I described.

Comment: @Scott Seidman Oh I see. But I didnt need to add it because I thought CM gain is too low and has no effect comparing to the Gain

Comment: Hard experience tells me that you should simulate what you want to run.  It may make a difference one time in a thousand, but it feels very silly when you went to all the trouble to run a simulation and still don't get it right.

Comment: Btw if it was constant offset I would subtract it and all would be fine, but this thing is nonlinear

Comment: @Scott Seidman Pls see my edit, I plotted this time with 2.5V common mode voltage.

Comment: @doncarlos, Vout/Vin changes nonlinearly, but that does not mean the problem is not a fixed offset.

Comment: @The Photon You are right, please see my edit EDIT2, I think this is what you meant before. I would be glad if you confirm it.

Comment: Yes, that's close enough to what I meant. If you have solved your problem, be sure to post an answer explaining the solution.

Comment: @doncarlos POST AN ANSWER, please. Don't answer within the question, that's bad practice in this site!

Comment: @Enric Blanco This is my first answer. I also added some extra I would be glad if you agree my answer. Its not practical to tie the inputs all the time.

Comment: You can also accept your own answer if you have solved the question. That will serve as a guide for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed ThePhoton's suggestion in the comments.

Here is how to solve this:

First take offset by tying inputs together and to the GND and measure the output voltage Vout. In this case -39.3478mV as shown below:

[image]

So this should be subtracted from any output voltage after any measurement. And when I do that gain looks 800 constant:

[image]

*I suppose if a strain_gage is mounted and fixed, an offset measurement can be taken before any moving measurement(without the procedure above). Voffset is the output voltage when the inputs are tied to GND.

Imagine when mounted the offset stress of the gage is X amount(Newton) and the voltage is Vxo = V1+Voffset . If the stress is varied ΔX amount there will be increase in output voltage as ΔV and the output will be V2=(V1+Voffset)+ΔV.
Now V2-V1 = ΔV. So the amplifier's Voffset is included in the first offset already.